# Stop anchors from jumping vertically

Tags: css, scroll, anchor

This is driving me nuts.

basically, I need to stop the page from jumping vertically when I use anchors in a horizontally sliding div. Currently, instead of just nicely jumping side to side, the page jumps vertically too, and thats a big issue. I have a fiddle here to explain it:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkp17fap/4/

Code looks like this:

```css
a  {
    color:#ccc;
    padding:8px;
    margin:2px;
    display:block;
}


div.container {
    width:250px;
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    background:#ccc;
    border:solid 1px #555;
}

div.wide {
    display:block;
    height:350px;
    width:auto;
}

div.inner {
    height:350px;
    width:250px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.blue {
    background:blue;
}

.red {
    background:red;
}

.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}

.green {
    background:green;
}

.white {
    background:white;
}

.black {
    background:black;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="wide">
        
        
        <div class="inner blue" id="one">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>  </div>
        <div class="inner red" id="two">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>  </div>
        <div class="inner yellow" id="three">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>  </div>
        <div class="inner green" id="four">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>  </div>
        <div class="inner white" id="five">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>  </div>
        <div class="inner black" id="six">  <a href="#one">ONE</a><br><a href="#two">TWO</a><br><a href="#three">THREE</a><br><a href="#four">FOUR</a><br><a href="#five">FIVE</a><br><a href="#six">SIX</a><br>   </div>
        
    </div>

</div> 

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, and now my brain is empty. Can anyone help remove that page vertical jump?

Oh, I'm also hoping for the simplest explanation possible, as this project will also be distributed on USB keys, and no doubt used in old sketchy browsers that have never properly worked. I'm super excited about that part.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you try to set body to margin:0

Comment: Yes I have. The problem is, the div on the page isn't at the top of the page, its in the middle. So, if you scroll vertically AT ALL. the whole bloody thing jumps.

Comment: First of all, that's a clever way to use pure css to change the background color on click. I have never seen that before. However, from what I can tell, because of this method you are using, I don't think you'll be able to prevent the jumping behavior. Is javascript out of the question?

Comment: Complementing @jlego 's answer, the _good ol'_ plain JavaScript would run just fine in most of older browsers and you could use it to change background color and much more. What's the reason for **not** using JavaScript?

Comment: The background color was just a way of showing the different divs. In the actual page, each div has a different image in it, as an emulator of a touchscreen product my company makes. Thanks for the Kudos though :)

So, each div has an image in it, and the links are meant to slide the containing div to the inner div that has the correct image. But again, that damn vertical jumping....

Is there a way of coding it so that any link with an ID turns off vertical scroll? I have jquery running for simple page transitions, but I am wary of getting too much code in there for older sketchy browsers...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gkp17fap/14/

I updated the fiddle to push the div down, creating vertical page scrolling. As you can see, when you click a link, it jumps vertically as well as sliding horizontally to show you the proper div. I need that vertical jump to stop. 

Thanks again for the help everybody!

Comment: It seems to be intended behavior for the browser to scroll/focus on an anchor when clicked. So you could use javascript to change that behavior, or maybe you could try placing your #target at the top of the page so it has nowhere to scroll to. On a side note, your HTML seems a little wonky for what you're doing, and I'm sure all those `br` tags are not helping either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from 2 directions. First of all the inner divs are not really floating left. `div.wide` has `width: auto;`, and because its parent has a fixed width of 250px, it takes 100% of just that, so it also has a (calculated) width of 250px. In consequence, your `div.inner`are not left and right of each other, but top and bottom.

Since you probably cannot apply a fixed width to `div.wide`because you might not know beforehand how many `div.inner` will be there in all cases, I suggest you either choose a width which will in all cases be wide enough to hold all left-floating `div.inner` next to each other, or you calculate the necessary width by counting `div.inner` and multiplying that with the width of `div.inner`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var noOfSlides = $(".inner").length;
  var slideWidth = $(".inner").first().width();
  $(".wide).css("width", (noOfSlides * slideWidth)+"px");
});
```

The second direction the problem might come from is the way page anchors work. But first try the solution I suggested and report if that works for you.

Comment: HI Connexo, thanks for the reply. 

I've tweaked the CSS to make the Wide div have a set width, just to   let the inner divs next horizontally. Same issue occurs though, with the vertical jumping. 

Such a small silly thing, but such a big issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkp17fap/16/

Comment: The main issue here is so obvious I didn't see it at first. Anchors are ALWAYS meant to jump to a vertical position, NEVER to a horizontal one. This whole thing won't work the way you intend it without "jumping".